# How to send HTTP request with authentication basic?

Tags: c++, http

I'm using SOCKET (WINSOCK2.H) to connect to IP camera.
After connect, I want to send the command "GET /nphMotionJpeg?Resolution=640x480&Quality=Standard HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n" to get video stream.
But this command is not successful because the camera is protected by authentication basic.

Now, I want to insert into request command username and password but i don't know the syntax to do it.

Comment: You'd do yourself a favour using something like [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) rather than trying to implement HTTP yourself. Since you appear to be using win32, you could even look into using [WinINet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383630%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

the syntax is explained in the related wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication